# Python Data Types: Should I use Methods or Operators?

Tags: python

When working with Data Types I can either use operators or methods:

```
test_dict = {
    "car": "Ford",
}

# Option 1 (operators)
if "car" in test_dict:
    print(test_dict["car"])

# Üption 2 (methods)
if test_dict.__contains__("car"):
    print(test_dict.__getitem__("car"))
```

Is there any difference between the two Options or do they do exactly the same? What is used more in Production and/or better code practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 is much more commonly used and much more readable:

```
# Option 1 (operators)
if "car" in test_dict:
    print(test_dict["car"])
```

Comment: This is an understatement.

Comment: Not only that, the operators literally call the magic methods under the hood, so they do exactly the same thing. I would go so far as to say option 2 is never used in production, and if it was it would almost immediately be removed in favor of using the operator directly.

Comment: @chepner I was unsure if I should write MUCH in all capitals but decided not to because maybe it could be considered rude